# mbed CLI: make.py: error: Could not find executable for ARM

Tags: c, command-line-interface, mbed

I'm trying to compile a program with the mbed CLI using the following command:

```
mbed compile -m UBLOX_C027 -t ARM
```

It results in the following error:

```
make.py: error: Could not find executable for ARM.
Currently set search path: No path set
```

How can I set the executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways, either:

- Set `ARM_PATH` in mbed_settings.py in the root folder of your project.
- Or make sure that ARMCC is in your path.

Note that `ARM` compiler target is for the commercial [ARM compiler](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/). If you're using [GCC ARM](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) use the `GCC_ARM` target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan, actually before coming back here I found that I didn't have a compiler installed yet and it's not part of mbed-os. I'm working on OSX so searched for a compiler on brew, which led me to https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-arm. After installing it and setting GCC_ARM_PATH everything worked. Not sure what the difference is between ARM / GCC_ARM though?

Comment: ARM is the ARMCC compiler, which is part of the Keil uVision IDE (and is relatively expensive). GCC_ARM is free and open source. [Some background here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908760/arm-cortex-m-compiler-differences).

Answer (score 7):

I know I am way too late but still if anyone is facing the same problem.
I solved it in this way in MAC OS.

1. Download GCC_ARM for MAC OS from here: https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads
2. Extract it in some location and set the path using mbed cli:

`mbed config -G GCC_ARM_PATH "/Users/amod-mac/Desktop/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin"`